# Как прижать футер в низ страницы?

Tags: html, css

Как прижать футер в низ страницы?

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
</body>
```